# Create submit button in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I am using `Jquery` to go through an array and make a new table row for each element in the array.
At the end of each row I want a submit button with the value `Add To Cart`.

Here's some relevant code:

```
var addToCartCell = document.createElement('td');
$(tableRow).append(addToCartCell);
```

To add the submit button, so far I have tried:

```
$("<input type='submit' value='Add To Cart'").appendTo(addToCartCell);
```

And,

```
$(addToCartCell).append("<input type='submit' value='Add To Cart'");
```

But to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing angle bracket in each case. Try:

```
$(addToCartCell).append('<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">');
```

Comment: Very good sir, I cant believe it was such a noob mistake. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things. Happens to us all :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing `/>`

```
$("<input type='submit' value='Add To Cart' />").appendTo(addToCartCell);
```